# How to link pixeled texture between Geometry nodes and Material?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make a procedural object where I can put a pixel art texture and get a voxel object. I want to be able to change one image and have either the geometry nodes or the material automatically use the same image. This is what I have so far.

I have a grid that goes through a Mesh to Points node and instanciate cubes, then merge by distance to make it one mesh. The texture's alpha selects the points.
[image]

The material is simple. Just texture through emission node.
[image]

With this result:

[image]

I tried making the color an output and attribute, then putting that attribute in the Material color.
[image]
[image]

but I get this

[image]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set *Attribute Domain* in output settings to *Face* or *Face corner*:

[image]

By default, it is vertex, so that color information stored in vertices, not faces.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this node setup:

[image]

you might need to play around a bit with the scale/multiply/add values for your image so that you can "see" someting.

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]